# addNoticeMessage Vs addNotice : how pass URL in message with new function

Tags: magento2, messages, deprecated

I wanted to add notice to page with URL

```
 $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
                __(
                    'Go to my account, <a href="%1"> My account</a>',
                    $this->urlInterface->getUrl('customer/account/')
                )
            );
```

But this gives
[image]
Previously I was using addNotice (Its deprecated now so wanted to replace it it with addNoticeMessage )

```
$this->messageManager->addNotice(
        __(
            'Go to my account, <a href="%1"> My account</a>',
            $this->urlInterface->getUrl('customer/account/')
        )
    );
```

it was giving desired result

[image]

How can pass URL in new **addNoticeMessage**

Comment: check this link --- https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/magento-2-add-anchor-link-to-success-or-error-message/

Comment: @MohitPatel already using the same in my code above

Comment: can you check this link - https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/displaying-complex-error-messages-in-magento-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using **addComplexNoticeMessage** method of `\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface`.

```
$this->messageManager->addComplexNoticeMessage(
            'complexMessage',
            [
                'url' => $this->urlInterface->getUrl('to/our/root')
            ]
        );
```

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\MessageConfigurationsPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configurationsMap" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="example" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="renderer" xsi:type="const">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\Renderer\BlockRenderer::CODE</item>
                <item name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Message_Example::messages/complexMessage.phtml</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**complexMessage.phtml**

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getData('url'))?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('click here')) ?></a>
```